# 80% Javascript Solution for Flags in Codility

Tags: javascript

Flags, the famous code challenge in Codility.

- [Question Definition](https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/10-prime_and_composite_numbers/flags/)
- [Official Answer](https://codility.com/media/train/solution-flags.pdf)
- [My Test Report](https://app.codility.com/demo/results/trainingZ3WDDH-NHM/)

I've tried several times and I'm pretty sure the bug is inside the function "CheckFlags" 
I've also tried the official solution provided by Codility and got 100% eventually. 
However, I cannot figure out why my checking algorithm fails and there are only three failed test data (check test report).

```
function solution(A) {

    let peakIndex = [];
    let peakCount = 0;

    for (let i = 1; i < A.length-1; i++) {
        if (A[i-1] < A[i] && A[i] > A[i+1]) {
            peakIndex[peakCount] = i;
            peakCount++;
        }
    }

    if (peakCount === 0 || peakCount === 1) 
        return peakCount;


    let left = 2;
    let right = peakCount;
    let result;

    while(right >= left) { // binary search

        let flags = Math.floor((left+right)/2)

        if (!CheckFlags(peakIndex, flags)) {
            right = flags - 1;    
        } else {
            result = flags;
            left = flags + 1;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

function CheckFlags (peakIndex, flags) {

    let flagCount = 1;
    let flagIndex = new Array(flags);
    flagIndex[0] = 0; // always include the first flag

    for (let peakIter = 1; peakIter < peakIndex.length && flagCount <= flags; peakIter++) {
        if (peakIndex[peakIter] - flagIndex[flagCount - 1] >= flags) {
            flagIndex[flagCount] = peakIndex[peakIter];
            flagCount++;

            if (flagCount === flags) 
                return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the line

```
flagIndex[0] = 0;
```

This line of code sets the location for the first flag index, but incorrectly assigns the first location instead of the location of the first peak. It should read

```
flagIndex[0] = peakIndex[0];
```

Comment: Thanks you for answering can you explain why your answer fix the problem

Comment: Good point, I have edited the answer to make it a little more informative.